# How to change the cursor on hover in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't find out on how I can change my cursor to a "pointer" or whatever it's called while hovering an image.

I have tried with MouseOver but I can't get it to work. Here's my current code;

```
private void image_Phone_MouseOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

However, the cursor doesn't change.

Comment: Have you tried handling MouseEnter and MouseLeave and setting the cursor to Hand and Default respectively?

Comment: I did indeed try MouseEnter after googling a while, but it wouldn't work either.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents();` call this after you set the cursor. The message loop wont be called so it's blocked...Using this will pump the message... Or try `image_phone.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;`

Comment: Tried that too @Zaggler.

Comment: @Chris Meller What one did you try, the `DoEvents` or actually setting the picturebox cursor?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Set appropriate cursor in control properties window.

Here's an example of setting "Hand" cursor for picturebox.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the best method, or if you're creating PictureBoxes dynamically within a flow layout, setting its Cursor property programatically. The problem I found with MouseEnter/Leave changes is that they didn't trigger properly and within the MouseHover event, the cursor started flickering between the hand and default states.

Answer (score 8):

This is a way to change the cursor when over the **actual** `Image`:

[image]

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Cursor = ImageArea(pictureBox1).Contains(e.Location) ?
                                                Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Default;
}

Rectangle ImageArea(PictureBox pbox)
{
    Size si = pbox.Image.Size;
    Size sp = pbox.ClientSize;
    float ri = 1f * si.Width / si.Height;
    float rp = 1f * sp.Width / sp.Height;
    if (rp > ri)
    {
        int width = si.Width * sp.Height / si.Height;
        int left = (sp.Width - width) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(left, 0, width, sp.Height);
    }
    else
    {
        int height = si.Height * sp.Width / si.Width;
        int top = (sp.Height - height) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(0, top, sp.Width, height);
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to re-calculate the `ImageArea` when changing the `Image` or the `SizeMode` or the `Size` of The `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 6):

For any PowerShell/Windows Forms programmers:

You can use this for basically every element in your form:

```
$pictureBox1.Add_MouseHover({ $this.Cursor = "Hand" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Cursor.Current use image_Phone.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

Comment: This wont work either, here's how it looks by a screenshot; http://prntscr.com/chk1k3

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the mouse down event change the cursor
2. than with the mouse move event check if location the same as image
3. Than wait for the mouse up event and set the default cursor

   - Or just set the property for the cursor

Answer (score 1):

In WinForms (assumption made by the tag) - there is a `Cursor` property on the PicutureBox control... (It's actually on `Control`) try setting that?